# Mongoid error "undefined method `delete' for :format:Symbol"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, nested, mongoid

I have 2 nested models:

```
class Interstate
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :url, :type => String
  field :time_zone, :type => String
  embeds_many :roadmaps
end

class Roadmap
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, :type => String
  field :privacy, :type => Integer
  field :interstate_id, :type => Integer
  embedded_in :interstate, :inverse_of => :roadmaps
end
```

I'm not sure about the difference between `has_many|belongs_to` and `embeds_many|embedded_in`, but according to documentations last is better for me, anyway both doesn't work. Also I have nested resources:

```
 resources :interstates do
   resources :roadmaps
 end
```

And Error appears when I'm trying to create Roadmap in Interstate.

Roadmap controller is standard scaffold with before_filter method for Interstate defining:

```
 private
 def get_interstate
   @interstate = Interstate.find(params[:interstate_id])
 end
```

In case with `embeds_many :roadmaps` and `embedded_in :interstate` other error occurs:

```
NoMethodError in Roadmaps#new

Showing /home/alder/RubymineProjects/interstate/app/views/roadmaps/_form.html.haml where line #1 raised:

undefined method `delete' for :format:Symbol

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: = simple_form_for(@interstate, @roadmap) do |f|
2:   = f.error_notification
3: 
4:   .inputs

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/roadmaps/new.html.haml

Rails.root: /home/alder/RubymineProjects/interstate
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/roadmaps/_form.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_roadmaps__form_html_haml___160176716082020505_38930380'
app/views/roadmaps/new.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_roadmaps_new_html_haml__4577296702858298215_34853620'
app/controllers/roadmaps_controller.rb:31:in `new'
```

Console:

```
undefined method `delete' for :format:Symbol (ActionView::Template::Error)
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/mongoid-2.3.2/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations.rb:80:in `notifying_parent?'                                                                                 
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/mongoid-2.3.2/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/embedded/remove.rb:30:in `block in persist'                                                                  
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/mongoid-2.3.2/lib/mongoid/persistence/deletion.rb:23:in `prepare'                                                                                             
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/mongoid-2.3.2/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/embedded/remove.rb:29:in `persist'                                                                           
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/mongoid-2.3.2/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:56:in `remove'                                                                                                       
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:392:in `apply_form_for_options!'                                                                      
/home/alder/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:365:in `form_for'
```

[Full stack](http://www.sourcepod.com/fgfhrz41-5868)

So, maybe I should add some options to cancel notifying, but more intresting why format is Symbol, I guess it should be Some Model Object. Perhaps `@interstate` is not the model.

This code works with sqlite db correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was in round brackets instead of squared.

`simple_form_for [@interstate, @roadmap]`